# Pictures not showing up in Photos after import

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, photos, import

I recently imported photos from my iPhone to my MacBook and using the "delete after import" function.

Now the photos aren't in the Photos library but it's not in my phone either. I've tried to restart the macbook and repair the photo library but both didn't work.

Are the photos just lost?

High Sierra 10.13.8 and IOS 14.8.1

Comment: It would be helpful to know the iOS and macOS versions of your phone and Mac to assist in troubleshooting.

Comment: Right, sorry. It's High Sierra 10.13.8 and IOS 14.8.1